# How to vertically align a floating table inside a td

Tags: html, css, inline

Is it possible to vertically align **table 3** at the bottom in the following example?

This is for a mail signature, hence the use of tables and the hack with `align` to make the tables responsive (they'll stack underneath each other if viewport gets too small). Now, the client wants the logo in **table 3** to be aligned at the bottom (see [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d6Re.png)) and I'm beginning to wonder if this is even possible while keeping it mobile friendly.

I've tried `vertical-alignment: bottom` pretty much everywhere and `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: 0;` on **table 3** to no avail. I'm guessing the `align="left"` overrides pretty much ever vertical alignment styling I'm trying to make.

```
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #000 solid; max-width: 903px; width: 100%">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- "responsive" tables -->

                <!-- table 1 -->
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #ff0000 solid; width: 300px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Company logo
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <!-- table 2 -->
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #00ff00 solid; width: 300px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Contact details<br>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <!-- table 3 -->
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #0000ff solid; width: 300px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Another logo
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vertical-align and give the cell a height using CSS.

```css
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.logoHolder td {
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}}
```

```html
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #000 solid; max-width: 903px; width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- "responsive" tables -->

      <!-- table 1 -->
      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #ff0000 solid; width: 300px;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Company logo
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <!-- table 2 -->
      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #00ff00 solid; width: 300px;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Contact details<br>
            <br>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <!-- table 3 -->
      <table class="logoHolder" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #0000ff solid; width: 300px;vertical-align: bottom;">
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
            Another logo
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That was quick! Unfortunately I can't do that, because when **table 3** floats underneath **table 2** there's considerable white space between the content due to **table 3s** fixed height.

Comment: If it only floats on mobile then you can use a CSS code that will only apply on desktop. I will modify my answer for that.

Comment: Thx again, we were able to test it now. Conditional fixed height doesn't work here either since every mail client renders the height of the middle block differently, so `table 3` never really aligns with the bottom on all of them.